# Can I ask about the risks of running an out of date Operating System?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, asking-questions

Lately, I've been thinking about the Windows 7 end of support, what kind of impact it could have (e.g. security and vulnerability wise).

I know it's dangerous, but I don't know if I'm still at risk of exposure if I'm just being extremely carely and not going on suspicious websites or such for example.

I've tried searching for information, but so far from what I could read (the existing questions and information I could find), it looks like I'd be safe if I turn on the computer and avoid using a web browser altogether (which I believe is wrong).

Comment: There's a bunch of similar ones asking about XP: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54733/security-of-a-windows-xp-system-after-april-8th-when-running-the-latest-firefox?rq=1 and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57203/specific-security-concerns-with-now-unupdatable-win-xp/57210 and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221348/how-to-explain-to-traditional-people-why-they-should-upgrade-their-old-windows-x If you asked the question you posed, it would likely be closed as a duplicate of one of those.